# Java jbytearray access in c (JNI)

Tags: java, visual-c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have a set of java classes that I need at my job to be ran in C/C++.

And, since I am fairly new to java, I am taking it one step at a time.  I've gotten to be able to call java with string, int double etc, but the end results will be getting a byte array back (a pdf document) so I tried sending back a simple two element byte array.

Here is the java:

```
public class ReturnData
{
    int returnValue;
    String Log;
    Byte[] data = new Byte[2];

     public ReturnData(int nRetVal, String szLog)
     {
         this.data[0] = 100;
         this.data[1] = 12;
         this.returnValue = nRetVal;
         this.Log = szLog;
     }
}
```

and here is the c++ code (JNI initialization removed.  It works for simple types so ...)

```
jbyteArray jbyteData = (jbyteArray)jniEnvironment->GetObjectField(jobjRetData,
    jniEnvironment->GetFieldID(clsReturn, "data", "Ljava/lang/ByteArray;"));
```

And now anytime I access the jbyteData element, such as:

```
jsize len = jniEnvironment->GetArrayLength(jbyteData);
```

I get an Exception

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
Message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other 
memory is corrupt.
```

Comment: Note that this problem would have been detected immediately if the return value from `GetObjectField()` had actually been checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the field `Byte[] data = new Byte[2];` to `byte[] data = new byte[2];`

Then in your JNI method use `GetFieldID(clsReturn, "data", "[B"));`

**Edit:** To be able to get the internal signature of each type (`[B` for `byte[]` in your case) you can declare the field you want to a class (let's call it `Test`), compile it and then run `javap -s Test`. It produces an output like below:

```
Compiled from "SimpleMain.java"
public class SimpleMain extends java.lang.Object{
public byte[] data;
  Signature: [B            // <-- signature shows the internal type 
public SimpleMain();
  Signature: ()V
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
}
```

Comment: Just curious, where are these data type strings defined.  I looked and looked and could not find any authoritative source, so I had to go by blog entries and web site questions.

Comment: @saunderl I have added an example of `javap` execution to my answer with the produced output. Check it out

Answer (score 2):

For the FieldID, I think you want to use `"[B"` instead of `"Ljava/lang/ByteArray;"`, which isn't actually a class.

Edit: since you're using the `Byte` class, which I missed in my original response, use "`[Ljava/lang/Byte;"` instead

Comment: +1 for showing how to use Byte.  I really needed to switch to byte (and you answered that as well.)